# Javascript doesn't work when textbox name contains square brackets

Tags: php, javascript

I've got this script for calculating square area, which works perfect:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
  one = document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value;
  two = document.autoSumForm.secondBox.value; 
  document.autoSumForm.Area.value = (one * 1) * (two * 1);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>

<form name="autoSumForm">
<input  size="3"  type=text name="firstBox" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">
<input  size="3"  type=text name="secondBox" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">
<input  size="4"  type=text name="Area" readonly="true">
</form>
```

But my problem is that I need the name of the third box to be *`Area[<?php echo $area['area_id']; ?>]`*

But I can't get the javascript to work, when I use brackets in the name.

Comment: Why you want to set an ID in textarea's name ? Will there be in this form more textareas ?

Comment: Where does your $area variable come from?

Comment: Your suggestion generally works with PHP @Michael and PHP sees `Area` variable as an array. Check whether your `$area['area_id']` contains any invalid character (space, hyphen, etc.) for a good array index. To work with JavaScript, the index must be numeric and (I think) should start with 0 and must be contiguous (0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note that you should not add the brackets if you don't need them!** It makes it unnecessary complex.

In your posted code there is no indication that you need those brackets. You normally add them if you have several input fields with the same name and you want PHP to create an array. For more information please refer to [*Variables From External Sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

In case you need them, you have to use bracket notation to access the field:

```
document.autoSumForm['Area[<?php echo $area["area_id"]; ?>]'].value = (one * 1) * (two * 1);
```

Also I would suggest to not pass a value inside the brackets in the name of the field. This would simplify your code to:

```
<input  size="4"  type=text name="Area[]" readonly="true">
```

and:

```
document.autoSumForm['Area[]'].value = (one * 1) * (two * 1);
```

PHP will then create an array with continuous numerical keys starting at `0`.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>While Felix's answer will work in most (all?) browsers, it should be noted that HTML names and IDs are supposed to be valid identifiers, which cannot contain square brackets.  The correct solution is to not use square brackets in your names and IDs.</strike>

**EDIT:**  I stand corrected.  In HTML 4, The 'id' attribute is type ID, but the 'name' attribute for form elements is type CDATA, so can contain practically anything.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html

I was probably thinking of meta 'name', which is type NAME.

Comment: True, but this is how it works in PHP if you want to have multiple values with the same name (so that it creates an array).

Comment: In the HTML5 spec the only characters not allowed in an ID attribute are white space. IIRC, the major browsers already behaved this way so it's not a compatibility-breaking change.  I believe the more or less the same rules apply to `name`, too.

Comment: IDs - yes, but not for names. Input names are intended to contain square brackets when an array of results is needed. E.g. multiple checkboxes like `<input type='checkbox' name='options[]' value='...'>`

Comment: @mkilmanas That's totally correct - for form elements, the type of the name attribute is CDATA, not ID or NAME.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add id to textarea

   `<input  size="4"  type=text name="Area" id="someid" readonly="true">`
2. Put value by id

   `document.getElementById('someid').value = (one * 1) * (two * 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I would add an 'id' attribute to the third box (third input) and give the id a value without square brackets.

Use the 'id' attribute to select the DOM element in your javascript code.  And let the 'name' attribute keeps its square brackets.